# clang: error: conflicting deployment targets on macOS 10.13.1 'make main'

Tags: c++, ios, terminal

I work on macOS High Sierra 10.13.1. I try to compile from terminal file main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {   
    cout << "Hello, World!\n";
    return 0;
}
```

I type: "make main" and get the following errors:

```
c++     main.cpp   -o main

clang: error: conflicting deployment targets, both 'WATCHOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' and 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' are present in environment

clang: error: conflicting deployment targets, both 'TVOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' and 'IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET' are present in environment

make: *** [main] Error 1
```

I have no problems with running projects in XCode.

Comment: how does your makefile look like?

Comment: I don't have one. Or at least can not find one. The same error I have when trying to execute: "g++ main.cpp" and similar comments.